# How can I show only the div which does not contain a check box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following div structure:

```
<div class="members-content">
<a>Studen ...</a>
</div>

<div class="members-content">
<a>Studen ...</a>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" >
</div>

<div class="members-content">
<a>Studen ...</a>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" >
</div>
```

How can I show only the div which DOES NOT contain a check box ?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to find and show the div that doesn't have a check box or is a simple `$('.members-content').Show()` good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `$('.members-content:not(:has(input))')`

Answer (score 1):

To show the one without a checkbox:

```
$("div.members-content:not(:has(:checkbox))").show();
```

To hide the ones with a checkbox:

```
$("div.members-content").has(":checkbox)").hide();

// could also hide with the following, but less effecient:
$("div.members-content:has(:checkbox)").hide();
```

Or, an arguably simpler approach is just to start by hiding them all and then show the one you want:

```
$("div.members-content").hide();
$("div.members-content:not(:has(:checkbox))").show();

// OR
var members = $("div.members-content");
members.hide();
members.not(":has(:checkbox)").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.members-content').hide();
$('div:not(:has(input[type="checkbox"]))').show()
```

This will hide everything except the div which does not have any checkbox

Working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/4kYcx/14/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(function(){
    $("div.members-content").filter(function(){
        return $(this).find(":checkbox").length > 0;
    }).hide();
});
```